# Angular how to modify component field in other component method

Tags: angular

I'm trying to modify my fields of my component in other component but values are not changed. Example I created component 1 with field A in component 2 I created method calculate with parameter A I'm making some calculations on parameter A but in my component 1 after method calculate variable A is not changed.

```
export class Component1 {
  A : number = 0;
 
  calculateA() {
    Component2.calculateA(this.A);
    // variable A is not changed
  }
}

export class Component2 {
  static calculateA(A : number) {
    A = 5;
  }
}
```

Why A value is not changed?

Comment: what is the trigger to this calculation? and what is the relationship between the components?

Comment: There is no reations between components. I'm trigger calculations on some event.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind This is not a proper way of component communication in angular. 
I would recommend you should use services.
You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).

In your problem you should return value of `A` from component2.

```
 static calculateA(A : number) {
  A = 5;
  return A;
}
```

Now to assign this value to A in component1 do this.

```
export class Component1{
 A : number = 0;
 calculateA() {
 this.A = Component2.calculateA(this.A);
  // variable A is not changed
}
}
```

Your code is not working because you are passing a `value` not a `reference`.
If you use primitive data types then it will be passed by value else reference will be passed.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, also to keep in mind that JavaScript passes primitive variables by value and not by reference.

Comment: What when I will have more than 1 variable should I use arrays ?

Comment: Yes you can use array. But if you are using array and passing it directly you wont have to return value. It will be passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Number parameters are a value object in JavaScript, this means that the value is passed in and changing the parameter in the function does not effect the source variable that was used for the parameter.

```js
let x = 5;

function func(val) {
  val = 10;
}

func(x);

console.log(x);
```

If you pass in a a parameter by object your function can change the value of the parameter but that is bad programming practice.

```js
let x = { prop: 5 };

function func(val) {
  val.prop = 10;
}

func(x);

console.log(x);
```

Read up on value vs reference objects.

That being said you are obviously very new to Angular, you are not ready to be learning Angular just yet, you need to learn RxJs first. Come back to learning Angular once you understand RxJs. If you don't know what an observable, subject or behavior subject are then you should be studying reactive programming not Angular.